# How to update row data in Datatable?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatable

I'm trying to update a row in Datatable used in my React app.

I save the Datatable object as well as the selected **rows** saved in my React component's state as `this.state.myTable` and `this.state.selected`.

I save the Datatable object initially like so:

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({ ... });

this.setState({ myTable: myTable });
```

I save the selected rows on row click event like so:

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
}).on('click', 'tr', function () {
    this.setState({ selected: this.state.myTable.rows('.selected') });
}.bind(this));
```

I update the **row** data (according to the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data())) like so:

```
function (newValue) {
    var data = this.state.selected.row().data();
    data.someValue = newValue
    this.state.selected.row().data(data).draw();
},
```

But the new data is not reflected in my Datatable unless I update some other row (but then only this row is updated and not that row).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your view will `re-render` whenever there is a `change in the state`. So when you are updating the value just use setState, instead of directly mutating the state.

```
function (newValue) {
    var dataType = {...this.state.selected};
    var data = dataType.row().data();
    data.someValue = newValue
    dataType.row().data(data).draw();
    this.setState({selected: dataType});
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#dataTable').on('click', '.update', function () {
        var tableRow = $('#dataTable').row($(this).parents('tr'));
        var rData = [
            test1,
            test1,
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="update">Update</a>',
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="delete">Delete</a>'
        ];
        $('#dataTable')
                .row( tableRow )
                .data(rData)
                .draw();
    });
});
```

You can use this code, it worked in our projects.